# Fully digital mathematics workflows?

Tags: soft-question

I've been thinking about how computer technology has changed math for practitioners. As a computer scientist self-learning math, it has taken a lot of mental rewiring to get myself to reach for pencil and paper nearby. For example, for doing "data science", I've found interactive notebooks like Jupyter Notebook to be extremely helpful in iterating.

**How have folks incorporated digital notebook environments into their mathematics workflows?**

I am aware of mathematica and sage, but I wonder if "practicing mathematicians" are able to immerse themselves in those tools, and whether the basic thought processes that compose mathematical research are able to be expressed within those environments.

Some sub-questions:

1) Are you able to entirely do your work within LaTeX? Or do you need a chalkboard or paper?

2) If you do use digital tools, do you use them for the transcribing features (LaTeX and ilk), the symbolic computations (auto-integrations, etc), or both?

--

Edit to add a link to this related post: [How Do You Actually Do Your Mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/how-do-you-actually-do-your-mathematics?rq=1)

The way that this question is different is I am asking specifically about how software is integrated in the way you "do" your mathematics.

Comment: workflows? what are they....?

Comment: I think that math and computational practice have a lot to offer each other. A lot of mathematical "assumption of prerequisites", "borrowing notation", and "referring to proofs in external resources" are problems of managing linked resources, which computer architectures have streamlined. And for me personally, no thinking aid has been better than a REPL on one hand, and pencil-and-paper on the other.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've edited the question with a helpful related Q that showed up once I submitted. I'm asking a similar question, except about how computers are integrated into the way you "do mathematics"